# datatable doesnt load properly when call with ajax (codeigniter)

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I have 2000 datas that I want to display with plug-in datatables.
When I call it with simple source code, it's working without any problem. Searching, pagination and sorting feature are great.
When I use ajax to call datas, all features didn't work. The data showing up, but datatables doesn't read any of it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctoG7.jpg)

as you guys can see in picture above, datatables doesn't read any data, but data showing up. and when I use any feature, showing up datas gone and become no record found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INvna.jpg)

This is my script ajax function

```
<script>
$(function(){   
    showDatek();

    function showDatek(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/getDatek',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html +='<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].a+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].b+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].c+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].d+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].e+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].f+'</td>'+                                                                                                           
                            '<td>'+
                            '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>';                                
                }
                $('#showdata').html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

here my table script which is in same file with function above.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>A</th>
                                    <th>B</th>
                                    <th>C</th>
                                    <th>D</th>
                                    <th>E</th>
                                    <th>F</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="showdata">

                            </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I appreciate any reply, thank before.

Answer (score 0):

The type in ajax refers to the method default is GET.And you have to call function when your page is loaded.i.e `<body onload="showDatek()">`

```
function showDatek(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/getDatek',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                html +='<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].a+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].b+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].c+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].d+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].e+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].f+'</td>'+                                                                                                           
                        '<td>'+
                        '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>'+
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>';                                
            }
            $('#showdata').html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: thanks for your reply, @hikmat
but unfortunatly, before this, I already tried like your post, 
I forgot to change it back :p, 
but it still doesn't work,